# How to know when CSS set through style property is applied to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Simple question, Is there an event or a callback tha signals that CSS set through the JS "style" property is applied and rendered to the DOM.
here is an example.

```
const elem = document.querySelector("#abc");
elem.style.color = "red";
excuteAfterCSSAppliedToDOM(() => {
 // some code to excute
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is applied immediately and synchronously when your code does the assignment. It'll get rendered on-screen the next time the page is painted. You can get a callback just *before* that happens by using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). For a callback soon after, use a nested `requestAnimationFrame` or a `setTimeout` with a timeout of zero:

```
function excuteAfterCSSAppliedToDOM(callback) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => callback()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, never thought to add another requestAnimationFrame